# Running shell command with git filter-branch

Tags: bash, git, shell, sh

I'm trying to build an application that change git commit history timestamp with git filter-branch. But I am getting wrong timestamp when I execute following shell script and check git commit history with "git log". Am I doing wrong with using function argument? Any help?

```
fix_commit_date() { 
    git filter-branch --env-filter \
    "if [ $GIT_COMMIT =  $(1) ]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=\"$(2)\"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\"$(2)\"
     fi" -f
}
fix_commit_date c1f456c87bd66cad07b24827946df5a44cac95f2 "Tue Mar 3 21:38:53 2009 -0800"
```

Comment: Why `$(1)`? Dont you want `${1}`, and preferably with quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following syntax is meant to evaluate code in a subshell and capture output:

```
$(code here)
```

Whereas the following syntax(es) capture *some* of the ways to dereference positional parameters (see `sh(1)` for more):

```
$1
${1}
```

So you are seeing incorrect results because you’ve attempted to run and capture output of the commands `1` and `2`, which in all likelihood don’t exist.

Switch to one of the second syntaxes. And prefer to double quote both expansions.